# How to change Content-Transfer-Encoding for email attachments?

Tags: email, thunderbird, character-encoding

I have signed up for http://eudyptula-challenge.org/ challenge and this accepts
email attachments only in simple text format. 
The files without extension (and also .zip file) are transferred with base64 encoding.
I want to send email attachment in simple text. This is how my makefile is transferred :-

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;
 name="Makefile"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="Makefile"

b2JqLW0gKz0gaGVsbG8yLm8KCmFsbDoKCW1ha2UgLUMgL2xpYi9tb2R1bGVzLyQoc2hlbGwg
dW5hbWUgLXIpL2J1aWxkIE09JChQV0QpIG1vZHVsZXMKCmNsZWFuOgoJbWFrZSAtQyAvbGli
L21vZHVsZXMvJChzaGVsbCB1bmFtZSAtcikvYnVpbGQgTT0kKFBXRCkgY2xlYW4KCg==
```

How to configure Thunderbird to send a attachment files in as simple text??
Or I should any other email server or tool to send email attachments in simple text??

Comment: It’s because the file is UTF-8-encoded text. E-Mails support only 7-bit ASCII as per specifications. Everything else has to be encoded somehow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in thunder bird 
Edit-> preference -> Display -> font -> advanced -> out going mail 
set it from UTF-8 to Western iso 8859-1

Comment: And to think we put up with unreadable email formatting still because back in the '80s when the MIME standard was cooked up, there were still systems that couldn't handle 8 bit text.  Will we ever leave that behind?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it will help with attachments.

Comment: @Tobu Oddly enough, it works.

Comment: This works !! I'm amazed :D

Comment: Weird, but it does work.

Comment: Once in a year, I bump into this issue and your answer helps me. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu (19.10 eoan) Thunderbird go to

> Edit -> Preferences -> Display -> Formatting tab -> Fonts & colors -> Advanced -> Text Encoding -> Outgoing Mail

and change UTF-8 to Western (ISO-8859-1).

Make sure to check when possible, use the default text encoding in replies checkbox. (Unless I did this, my attachments were still going in previous encoding).

Hope this helps!